# "invalid byte sequence" running remote code via ssh from Windows; macOS OK

Tags: ruby, windows, macos, ssh, cygwin

When I run the following from a Windows computer (via [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com)) I get an error:

```
ssh bob@linux-server.com 'cd ./bin && ./script.rb'
./script.rb:2:in `gsub': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError)
```

Running the same code (the entire `ssh` line above) from Terminal on Mac is successful.

How can this be?

This is the two-line script named `script.rb` above:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
File.open('/home/bob/input.txt').read.gsub(/A/, 'B')
```

More info...

I **emptied** the input file `input.txt` above, and still its size as reported by `ls -l input.txt` and `stat input.txt` is `3`. Running `file input.txt` reports `UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators`; if I place just one character into `input.txt`, it's size becomes `5` and `file` reports it as `UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text`.

The Ruby version on the Linux server is `2.2.7p470` and RubyGems (`gem --version`) is `2.6.11`.

The file `input.txt` is generated by a 3rd party program (it is a data export).

Running `File.open('/home/bob/input.txt').read.encoding` gives `US-ASCII` when executed from Windows/Cygwin/ssh and `UTF-8` from macOS/Terminal/ssh.

Comment: I posted answer below.  But if that doesn't work can you post contents of `/home/bob/file.txt` file?

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help me. I tried `#encoding: utf-8` but it didn't help. Regarding your second suggestion about running `gem update` with the `LANG` setting... I am worried that it will not help because this problem is on the remote *Linux* server I'd named `server.com` in my question (now renamed to `linux-server.com`). The Windows machine is running Cygwin, and from a Cygwin `bash` terminal I am simply executing the `ssh` command. Windows and Cygwin "do not know" that I am executing ruby on the remote end. Oh, and I've emptied the input file (see the update in my question).

Comment: what version of ruby, ruby gems, are you using on the linux server?

Comment: How are you editing the text file? It seems that ruby on your linux server thinks the text file is not using UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: What does `File.open('/home/bob/input.txt').read.encoding` say? Sounds like you have a UTF-8 file (with Byte Order Marker) but it is being read as ASCII on Windows.

Comment: I added the versions to my question. The file is generated by a 3rd party program, but when I edit it, I use `vim 7.4`.

Comment: I updated my question with the requested encoding info.

Comment: It's so puzzling (and frustrating!) that Ruby's execution on a Linux server can be affected by how it is called via ssh (whether it's from Windows or macOS). How can this be?

Comment: I found a solution and posted it as an answer. If someone finds a better solution, I will gladly select their answer. Thanks to @lacostenycoder and @ mu-is-too-short for trying to help me!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after the first line of your script.rb file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#encoding: utf-8
File.open('/home/bob/file.txt').read.gsub(/A/, 'B')
```

If that doesn't fix it see this https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/863
You may need to run this on your Windows machine:

```
LANG="${LANG%%.*}.BINARY" gem update
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem. Though, my shell on the server is `bash`, so I used `~/.bash_profile`:

> Try adding or editing the `~/.profile` file for it to correctly export
>   your locale settings upon initiating a new session.
>
> ```
> export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8  
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> ```

Source: [How to get UTF-8 locale when connecting via SSH to MacOSX from PuTTY (Windows)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/158675/71752)

Note: It works with either one *or* both of the above variables. It would be nice to know why.